# API request returns crap in some cases

Tags: php, encoding, rotten-tomatoes

I'm using rotten tomatoes API and when I try to get movie information sometimes it returns me normal json as it suppose to, but there are movies in which case it returns something like this

```
���������[o7���+|�Y��,��nhҠMQ�!p�#--.� ��U����������A�����̙�߽��׃�J\M���(���:W�k���F���
```

And so on...

I use php to do request, tried to do it with `file_get_contents` and CURL, result is the same. What it can be?

Comment: Without any code snippet and a specific case that we can try to reproduce your result, it can be anything really.

Comment: no code is there almost. As i said i use file_get_contents and then printing it

Comment: What is the encoding of your webpage?

Comment: Do you use json_decode on the data you receive from the API? There is a exemple here: http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples What happen if you try this exemple?

Comment: MrShibby, when I'm using json_decode it returns nothing. When I do it returns crap. Yes, i did try that example

Comment: Can you show the response header you get when calling the api?

Comment: {
    "Cache-Control": "must-revalidate",
    "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Content-Language": "en-US",
    "Content-Type": "text/javascript;charset=ISO-8859-1",
    "Date": "Tue, 11 Feb 2014 12:52:11 GMT",
    "Expires": "-1",
    "Server": "Mashery Proxy",
    "Vary": "User-Agent,Accept-Encoding",
    "X-Mashery-Responder": "prod-j-worker-us-east-1d-35.mashery.com",
    "Content-Length": "1029",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your responses are in gzip format.That's why you have special characters.

You can probably use the "gzdecode" function when you encounter that kind of response:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

See here : http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/156340/2

There are apparently some solutions that may help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching for it about a day, apparently not good... Thanks again